# YandexMaps. Обработчик событий (клик) на описание метки

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

На карте есть метки с контентом (iconContentLayout). В этом контенте необходимо реализовать элементарный slideToggle. Но в документации не нашел обработчика на iconContentLayout, только на саму метку (ее картинку). Возможно ли как нибудь обойти или по другому реализовать это?

Пробовал с балунами, но у меня по умолчанию все должны быть открыты, а яндекс позволяет только одному быть открытым за раз.

Обычный JS/Jquery не отрабатывает клик.

[Документация про обработчики событий](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/archive/doc/jsapi/1.x/ref/reference/events-docpage/)

Answer (score 0):

Вот на что нужно обратить внимание:

При добавлении геообъектов на карту их соответствующие DOM-элементы размещаются под слоем, на котором реализуется подписка на DOM-события. Это означает, что события геообъектов карты не отслеживаются на уровне DOM. Интерактивность геообъектов реализуется за счет активных областей (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/layouts-docpage/ ).

Метка, чтобы ловить события мышки, использует активную область. По умолчанию при задании своего HTML макета фигура активной области не задается, и её нужно задать самостоятельно. Это можно сделать при помощи опции метки iconShape в виде JSON описания геометрии (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape )

Взял пример с HTML макетом метки отсюда: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape
и добавил обработчик клика.

```js
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.7, 37.6],
        zoom: 10,
        controls: []
    });

    // Создание метки с квадратной активной областью.
    var squareLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="placemark_layout_container"><div class="square_layout">$</div></div>');

    var squarePlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
        [55.725118, 37.682145], {
            hintContent: 'Метка с прямоугольным HTML макетом'
        }, {
            iconLayout: squareLayout,
            // Описываем фигуру активной области "Прямоугольник".
            iconShape: {
                type: 'Rectangle',
                // Прямоугольник описывается в виде двух точек - верхней левой и нижней правой.
                coordinates: [
                    [-25, -25], [25, 25]
                ]
            }
        }
    );
    map.geoObjects.add(squarePlacemark);
    

    // Создание метки с круглой активной областью.
    var circleLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="placemark_layout_container"><div class="circle_layout">#</div></div>');

    var circlePlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
        [55.783202, 37.605584], {
            hintContent: 'Метка с круглым HTML макетом'
        }, {
            iconLayout: circleLayout,
            // Описываем фигуру активной области "Круг".
            iconShape: {
                type: 'Circle',
                // Круг описывается в виде центра и радиуса
                coordinates: [0, 0],
                radius: 25
            }
        }
    );
    map.geoObjects.add(circlePlacemark);

    // Создание метки со сложной фигурой активной области.
    var polygonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="placemark_layout_container"><div class="polygon_layout">!</div></div>');

    var polygonPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
        [55.662693, 37.558416], {
            hintContent: 'HTML метка сложной формы'
        }, {
            iconLayout: polygonLayout,
            // Описываем фигуру активной области "Полигон".
            iconShape: {   
                type: 'Polygon',
                // Полигон описывается в виде трехмерного массива. Массив верхнего уровня содержит контуры полигона. 
                // Первый элемента массива - это внешний контур, а остальные - внутренние.
                coordinates: [
                    // Описание внешнего контура полигона в виде массива координат.
                    [[-28,-76],[28,-76],[28,-20],[12,-20],[0,-4],[-12,-20],[-28,-20]]
                    // , ... Описание внутренних контуров - пустых областей внутри внешнего.
                ]
            }
        }
    );
    map.geoObjects.add(polygonPlacemark);

    // Подпишемся на событие клика
    map.geoObjects.events.add('click', function (e) {
        // Получим ссылку на геообъект, по которому кликнул пользователь.
        var target = e.get('target');
        alert(target.properties._data.hintContent);
        // Переместим центр карты по координатам метки с учётом заданных отступов.
        map.panTo(target.geometry.getCoordinates(), {useMapMargin: true});
    });

    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Задание фигуры активной области HTML макету метки</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!--
        Укажите свой API-ключ. Тестовый ключ НЕ БУДЕТ работать на других сайтах.
        Получить ключ можно в Кабинете разработчика: https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/keys/
    -->
 <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU&amp;apikey=<ваш API-ключ>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="placemark_shape.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .placemark_layout_container { 
            position: relative;
            font-family: Georgia;
            font-size: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        /* Квадратный макет метки */
        .square_layout {
            position: absolute;
            left: -23px;
            top: -23px;
            width: 46px;
            height: 46px;
            line-height: 46px;
            border: 2px solid #218703;
            background-color: #F8FDF7;
            color: #218703;
        }
        
        /* Круглый макет метки */
        .circle_layout {
            background-color: white;
            position: absolute;
            left: -23px;
            top: -23px;
            width: 46px;
            height: 46px;
            border: 2px solid #225D9C;
            color: #225D9C;
            line-height: 46px;
            /* Это CSS свойство не будет работать в Internet Explorer 8 */
            border-radius: 50px;
        }
        
        /* Макет метки с "хвостиком" */
        .polygon_layout {
            position: relative;
            background: #ffffff;
            border: 4px solid #943A43;
            width: 50px; 
            height: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            left: -28px;
            top: -76px;
            color: #943A43;
        }
        
        .polygon_layout:after, .polygon_layout:before {
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            border: solid transparent;
            content: " ";
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }
        
        .polygon_layout:after {
            border-top-color: #943A43;
            border-width: 10px;
            margin-left: -10px;
        }
        
        .polygon_layout:before {
            border-top-color: #943A43;
            border-width: 16px;
            margin-left: -16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Но мне необходимо отработать клик не по самой метке, а по элементу в ее контенте (iconContentLayout), там HTML код. По самой метке я нашел обработчик.

Comment: Дополнил ответ. У меня не получилось больше одной активной области, увы.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за ответ) Не обратил внимание на слои. Но опять же мне  не подойдет.  В iconContentLayout  есть 3 активные кнопки, которые отвечают за разный функционал. То есть необходимо отрабатывать клик именно по ним, а не по самой метке  =(

Answer (score 0):

Перед  iconLayout: polygonLayout,
напишите

pane: 'overlaps',

Это пейн для объектов, не требующих использования активных областей для реализации своей интерактивности;